# Shortcut to switch to full screen apps

Tags: macos, shortcut

There is a shortcut to switch to desktop 1...N in OS X.
But usually I have only one desktop and other apps (Chrome, iTerm, etc) in full screen mode.

Is there a way to make shortcuts to switch to these apps?

For example, I would like this configuration:

- **F1** - switch to desktop, it holds Skype, Finder, etc (already done)
- **F2** - switch to Chrome (full screen)
- **F3** - switch to iTerm (full screen)
- and so on